# Undefined index for the obtained value from get

Tags: php

I am getting an undefined index error for this line:

```
$msg = $_GET['msg'];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+Notice%3A+Undefined+index

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(array_key_exists('msg',$_GET))
{
//Your Code

}
```